# Custom profiler for UWP apps

Tags: debugging, profiling, uwp, profiler, .net-core

I'm trying to rewrite IL code dynamically at runtime. While this is quite well documented for .NET framework applications by using the [Profiling API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384493%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) I can't find anything similar for UWP applications.

Because I have a suite of automated function tests, I need to setup the profiling environment and start a sample app programmatically.

#### Attempt 1

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35612194/suspend-windows-10-store-app-on-launch) explains how to enable a debugger (as far as I understand a profiler is essentially a debugger) and programmatically start a UWP app.

So from my bootstrapper I call `IPackageDebugSettings::EnableDebugging` followed by `IApplicationActivationManager::ActivateApplication`.

Anyway I can't figure out how to implement the debugger. The debugger (which is an executable) is called with the following arguments:

```
-p 3836 -tid 6180
```

Both numbers change on every run. While `p` seems to be the process id of the debugged process, I have no idea what `tid` could be or how I have to use the arguments to control the debugged app (register for module load events, trigger rejits etc.).

#### Attempt 2

I found [this issue](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/445) on the Core CLR repo which is about enabling the Profiling API for Core CLR apps. The issue contains a [link](https://github.com/david-mitchell/CoreCLRProfiler) to a sample profiler repo.

So profiling for Core CLR apps seems to basically work the same way as it does in .NET framework apps (with some restrictions). From my bootstrapper I tried to set the appropriate environment variables (i.e. `CORECLR_ENABLE_PROFILING`, `CORECLR_PROFILER` and `CORECLR_PROFILER_PATH`) followed by `IApplicationActivationManager::ActivateApplication`.
However the profiler doesn't attach.

I'm quite sure that in general it is possible to profile UWP applications because JetBrains' dotTrace can do it.

Any ideas?